# Running Dot Net project exe on Linux which makes use of System.Management to get USB Device information

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, system.management

Hi, I have created a Dot Net application in C# to get USB Device Information like DeviceID, Caption, ClassGUID etc using System.Management Namespace. I'm using the ManagementObjectSearcher Method to fetch the value from Win32_DiskDrive. It's running fine on Windows. I want to run it on Linux machine. You can run Dot Net applications on Linux machine using Mono.

http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

When i run my application's exe on Linux using Mono i get the following error:

```
    Missing method .ctor in assembly /home/dvimay11/USBCamInfoNew/Debug/System.Management.dll, type System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /home/dvimay11/USBCamInfoNew/Debug/System.Management.dll mtoken: 0x0a000009

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Management'.
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo.GetUSBDevices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo.LoadUSBInfo () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) USBCamInfo.USBInfo:.ctor ()
  at USBCamInfo.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Reflection.AssemblySignatureKeyAttribute' from assembly 'System.Management'.
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo.GetUSBDevices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo.LoadUSBInfo () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at USBCamInfo.USBInfo..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) USBCamInfo.USBInfo:.ctor ()
  at USBCamInfo.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue. I wanted to know how i can run my Dot Net exe on a Linux machine using the System.Management Namespace to retrieve information of USB Device

Thanks

Comment: This is probably not supported on Mono because system management stuff is wildly different on Linux (and potentially other platfomrs)

Comment: Is there any way to fetch USB Information like USB ID, Device Information, Manufacturer etc on Linux and can i integrate it in my Dot Net Application.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Mono Project Roadmap](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Project_Roadmap#Unsupported_technologies) you'll find that `System.Management` is Windows specific and there are no plans to support it.

You could use [SharpUsbLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx) instead which has support for USB under Linux.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Is there any way i can make this run. Any other way to fetch USB information on Linux. I can make changes accordingly in my Dot Net Application and built it and then use it on Linux.

Comment: sounds like you need a refactor to a set of services that can then be platform specific bits to run (e.g. you create a *.services.net and *.services.mono project, with a *.services project that contains interfaces) then in each of the implementation projects, do your IoC injection whree appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richard. Can you please elaborate the process you have explained to me in a bit detail. If you can just help me with a link of any forums or blogs explaining the above process you have explained to me, i would be highly grateful to you. Thanks.